# Passing parameters a a string to execvp

Tags: c, parameters, parameter-passing, exec

I have the below code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int i, a=9;
        int length = 0;
        const char fail[20] = "Missing Arguments\n";
        char s1[512] = "";
        char s2[15] = "./calc_prizes";

        for (i=1; i<argc; i++) {
            length += sprintf(s1+length, " %s", argv[i]);
        }
        strcat(s2, s1);


        while(++a < argc) {
            if(fork() == 0) {
                char* arg[] = {s2, s1, NULL};   //this is the part that's wrong
                execvp(arg[0],arg);
                exit(1);
            }
            else
                wait(NULL);
        }   
        return 0;
    }
```

S2 stores the name of the program, s1 the parameters collects the parameters. I can't seem to run the program with the parameters with execvp, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `execvp(arg[0], arg + 1);` should do the trick.

Comment: Why are you doing `strcat(s2, s1);`? It is good to add following details in the question - 1. The command line arguments passing to this program. 2. Interprete `a=9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason of `execvp` failing could be this:

```
strcat(s2, s1);
```

[*I hope you have ensured that `s2` is large enough to contain the concatenated resulting string otherwise its buffer overflow, which is a different but certainly a problem in your code.*]
Here you are concatenating the `s1` to `s2` and `s2` is the name of the program you want to execute. In the `while` loop, you are doing:

```
char* arg[] = {s2, s1, NULL};
```

The `arg[0]` pointing to `s2` (concatenated string) and you are passing this as the first argument to `execvp`:

```
execvp(arg[0],arg);
```

[**execvp**](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp):

> The execv(), execvp(), and execvpe() functions provide an array of pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list available to the new program. **The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed.** The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer. [*emphasis mine*]

Hence, to call `execvp` successfully you should have the first argument as the name of the executable file which is `./calc_prizes` in your case.